# info@email for several people of one open another should saw it

Tags: email, alias, forwarding

We have an email address info@ourcompany.com which forward with alias to couple email addresses of our company to work.
What we need: if one of them (working people) open a message other will see that message already was opened. How it make to reallity?

It email works on google and with alias now, those forward messages to three email such as abdulova@ourcompany.com...
They need to know what massges already opened, because they make a contact with people via email that become to trouble like as recontact twice or more time with clients of out company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.  When the email is sent to info@you.com and forwarded onto person@you.com and person2@you.com and person3@you.com, the email is actually duplicated - it's no longer the same email.

What you should look into is a single mailbox which they all have access to - although I cannot advise on this as I don't know what you are using as a mail server.

If you can run an Exchange Server, this is simple to do with the shared mailbox functionality.

With Gmail, you would most likely need to [look at this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430) (Gmail collaboration through shared mailboxes).

For other mail services, I don't know as I've never tried.

Another possibility is setting up [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) on a single mailbox so that multiple users can access and sync the mailbox via a mail server.  In this scenario, all users would have an email client (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc) linked to the same mailbox, but would also have their own account setup - this way, they could reply as themselves if needed.